# Flink How to Write DataSet As Parquet files in S3?

Tags: apache-flink, parquet

How to write DataSet as Parquet files in s3 bucket using Flink. Is there any direct function like spark : DF.write.parquet("write in parquet")

Please help me how to write flink Dataset in parquet format.

I am stuck when trying to convert my DataSet to (Void,GenericRecord)

```
    DataSet<Tuple2<Void,GenericRecord>> df = allEvents.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<LongWritable, Text>, Tuple2<Void, GenericRecord>>() {
                @Override
                public void flatMap(Tuple2<LongWritable, Text> longWritableTextTuple2, Collector<Tuple2<Void, GenericRecord>> collector) throws Exception {
                    JsonAvroConverter converter = new JsonAvroConverter();
                    Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new File("test.avsc"));
                    try {
                        GenericRecord record = converter.convertToGenericDataRecord(longWritableTextTuple2.f1.toString().getBytes(), schema);
                        collector.collect( new Tuple2<Void,GenericRecord>(null,record));
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("error in converting to avro")
                    }
                }
                });
        Job job = Job.getInstance();
        HadoopOutputFormat parquetFormat = new HadoopOutputFormat<Void, GenericRecord>(new AvroParquetOutputFormat(), job);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputPath));
        df.output(parquetFormat);
        env.execute();
```

Please help me with what I am doing wrong. I am getting Exception and this 
code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little more complicated than that with Spark. The only way I was able to read and write Parquet data in Flink is through Hadoop & MapReduce compatibility. You need `hadoop-mapreduce-client-core` and `flink-hadoop-compatibility` in Your dependencies.
Then You need to create a proper `HadoopOutoutFormat`. You need to do something like this:

```
val job = Job.getInstance()
val hadoopOutFormat = new hadoop.mapreduce.HadoopOutputFormat[Void, SomeType](new AvroParquetOutputFormat(), job)
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, [somePath])
```

And  then You can do:

```
dataStream.writeUsingOutputFormat(hadoopOutFormat)
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say which exception you are getting but here is a complete example on how to achieve this.

The main points are:

- Use `org.apache.flink.api.java.hadoop.mapreduce.HadoopOutputFormat`

  - From dependency `org.apache.flink:flink-hadoop-compatibility_2.11:1.11.0`
  - `HadoopOutputFormat` is an adapter that allows you to use output formats developed for Hadoop
  - You need a `DataSet<Tuple2<Void,IndexedRecord>>`, because hadoop's `OutputFormat<K,V>` works with key-value pairs, the key we are not interested in so we use `Void` for the key type, and the value needs to be an Avro's `IndexedRecord` or `GenericRecord`.
- Use `org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetOutputFormat<IndexedRecord>`

  - From dependency `org.apache.parquet:parquet-avro:1.11.1`
  - This hadoop's [OutputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/OutputFormat.html) produces Parquet
  - This inherits from `org.apache.parquet.hadoop.FileOutputFormat<Void, IndexedRecord>`
- Create your own subclass of [`IndexedRecord`](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/org/apache/avro/generic/IndexedRecord.html)

  - You can't use `new GenericData.Record(schema)` because a record like this is no serializable `java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.avro.Schema$Field is not serializable` and Flink requires it to be serializable.
  - You still need to provide a `getSchema()` method, but you can either return `null` or return a [`Schema`](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/org/apache/avro/Schema.html) that you hold in a static member (so that it doesn't need to be serialized, and you avoid the `java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.avro.Schema$Field is not serializable`)

The source code

```
import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.generic.IndexedRecord;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.NotImplementedException;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.hadoop.mapreduce.HadoopOutputFormat;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetOutputFormat;
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.metadata.CompressionCodecName;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;


public class MyParquetTest implements Serializable {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new MyParquetTest().start();

    }

    private void start() throws Exception {

        final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment();
        Configuration parameters = new Configuration();

        Stream<String> stringStream = IntStream.range(1, 100).mapToObj(n -> String.format("Entry %d", n));
        DataSet<String> text = env.fromCollection(stringStream.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)));

        Job job = Job.getInstance();
        HadoopOutputFormat<Void, IndexedRecord>  hadoopOutputFormat = new HadoopOutputFormat<>(new AvroParquetOutputFormat<IndexedRecord>(), job);
        FileOutputFormat.setCompressOutput(job, true);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputCompressorClass(job, CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY.getHadoopCompressionCodecClass());
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("./my-parquet"));
        final Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(MyRecord.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("schema.avsc"));
        AvroParquetOutputFormat.setSchema(job, schema);

        DataSet<Tuple2<Void, IndexedRecord>> text2 = text.map(new MapFunction<String, Tuple2<Void, IndexedRecord>>() {
            @Override
            public Tuple2<Void, IndexedRecord> map(String value) throws Exception {
                return Tuple2.of(null, new MyRecord(value));
//              IndexedRecord record = new GenericData.Record(schema); // won't work becuase Schema$Field is not serializable
//              record.put(0, value);
//              return Tuple2.of(null, record);
            }
        });

        text2.output(hadoopOutputFormat);
        env.execute("Flink Batch Java API Skeleton");
    }

    public static class MyRecord implements IndexedRecord {

        private static  Schema schema;

        static {
            try {
                schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(MyRecord.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("schema.avsc"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private final String value;

        public MyRecord(String value) {
            this.value= value;
        }

        @Override
        public void put(int i, Object v) {
            throw new NotImplementedException("You can't update this IndexedRecord");
        }

        @Override
        public Object get(int i) {
            return this.value;
        }

        @Override
        public Schema getSchema() {
            return schema; // or just return null and remove the schema member
        }
    }
}
```

The `schema.avsc` is simply

```
{
  "name": "aa",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "value", "type": "string"}
  ]
}
```

and the dependencies:

```
implementation "org.apache.flink:flink-java:${flinkVersion}"
implementation "org.apache.flink:flink-avro:${flinkVersion}"
implementation "org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java_${scalaBinaryVersion}:${flinkVersion}"
implementation "org.apache.flink:flink-hadoop-compatibility_${scalaBinaryVersion}:${flinkVersion}"
implementation "org.apache.parquet:parquet-avro:1.11.1"
implementation "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.8.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll create a Flink OutputFormat via `new HadoopOutputFormat(parquetOutputFormat, job)`, and then pass that to `DataSet.output(xxx)`.

The job comes from...

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;

...

Job job = Job.getInstance();
```

The `parquetOutputFormat` is created via:

```
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat;

...
ParquetOutputFormat<MyOutputType> parquetOutputFormat = new ParquetOutputFormat<>();
```

See https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.parquet/parquet-hadoop/1.10.1/org/apache/parquet/hadoop/ParquetOutputFormat.html

Comment: I am still not clear if I just want to read a filed with JSON and let's created a Dataset<String> then how I will write this to parquet format. Is I have to define avro schema for my json data. ? Please provide some details as I am new to this.

Comment: Creating an Avro schema for writing to Parquet is common practice, yes (e.g. see https://netjs.blogspot.com/2018/07/how-to-read-and-write-parquet-file-hadoop.html). Note that this question about how to do it isn't a Flink issue, you might want to ask a new question tagged for Parquet and Avro.